# Angular Seed Template Lazy Load Module run time error after bundling systemjs Error: Cannot find 'BeerModule' in 'app/beer/beer.module'

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

```
   ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find 'BeerModule' in 'app/beer/beer.module'
        Error: Cannot find 'BeerModule' in 'app/beer/beer.module'
            at g (shims.js?1498055735607:6)
            at checkNotEmpty (app.js?1498055735609:47)
            at app.js?1498055735609:51
            at t.invoke (shims.js?1498055735607:7)
            at Object.onInvoke (app.js?1498055735609:50)
            at t.invoke (shims.js?1498055735607:7)
            at e.run (shims.js?1498055735607:6)
            at shims.js?1498055735607:6
            at t.invokeTask (shims.js?1498055735607:7)
            at Object.onInvokeTask (app.js?1498055735609:50)
            at t.invokeTask (shims.js?1498055735607:7)
            at e.runTask (shims.js?1498055735607:6)
            at a (shims.js?1498055735607:6)
            at XMLHttpRequest.invoke (shims.js?1498055735607:7)
            at g (shims.js?1498055735607:6)
            at checkNotEmpty (app.js?1498055735609:47)
            at app.js?1498055735609:51
            at t.invoke (shims.js?1498055735607:7)
            at Object.onInvoke (app.js?1498055735609:50)
            at t.invoke (shims.js?1498055735607:7)
            at e.run (shims.js?1498055735607:6)
            at shims.js?1498055735607:6
            at t.invokeTask (shims.js?1498055735607:7)
            at Object.onInvokeTask (app.js?1498055735609:50)
            at t.invokeTask (shims.js?1498055735607:7)
            at e.runTask (shims.js?1498055735607:6)
            at a (shims.js?1498055735607:6)
            at XMLHttpRequest.invoke (shims.js?1498055735607:7)
            at g (shims.js?1498055735607:6)
            at f (shims.js?1498055735607:6)
            at f (shims.js?1498055735607:6)
            at shims.js?1498055735607:6
            at t.invokeTask (shims.js?1498055735607:7)
            at Object.onInvokeTask (app.js?1498055735609:50)
            at t.invokeTask (shims.js?1498055735607:7)
            at e.runTask (shims.js?1498055735607:6)
            at a (shims.js?1498055735607:6)
            at XMLHttpRequest.invoke (shims.js?1498055735607:7)
```

I am try to do lazy loading module using Angular Seed Template : https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed/pull/1714

I had follow all the steps and can do successful production build, its working in development environment.

Getting run time error while loading lazy module, 'module.js' is download success.

Comment: The error message in the image differs from the error message in the posted stack trace. Typo?

Comment: @The Head Rush, thanks